# Move /home to a different disk

Tags: directory

Currently my `/home` partition and `/` are on different disks (configured at install time). Can anyone guide me to move the `/home` directory to the disk where my `/` currently resides in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a new folder `/new_home`.
2. Use rsync to migrate all data from /home into `/new_home`. (See instructions at wiki)
3. Edit fstab to remove the mount for `/home/`
4. Unmount `/home/`
5. Delete `/home` (This only deletes the empty folder)
6. Rename `new_home` to `home`

You may need to resize your partitions to make space for your new home directory using `gparted`. Also gparted can help you reclaim space after moving home.

Reference: [Moving home](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) at Ubuntu Wiki

Comment: I can do this on a live system without any issues, right?

Comment: @Oxwivi  Do it as a different user than the one you're migrating, preferably.

Comment: @belacqua Will it make a difference? I mean a directory will also be created for the new user in `/home`.

Comment: @Oxwivi  It probably isn't absolutely necessary, but there can be temp files, session-specific data, etc. that would be better moved from a logged-out state.  I usually do this kind of thing from an X-less session from root, from a liveCD, or with a temp user (e.g., adduser blah, and use to sudo).  See also cweiske's first two steps.   For the temp user, yes, it would be ideal to modify the home dir mount point (move it to / for example).

Comment: @belacqua Okay, I understand now, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Oxwivi Cool -- good luck.

Comment: @Oxwivi use `sudo adduser temp --home /tmp/t` followed by `sudo adduser temp admin` to add temp user to the admin group (So you can mount and unmount stuff). And remove the user later.

Answer (score 4):

1. logoff
2. logon as root on the terminal (press ctrl+alt+F1 to get to the shell, you can go back with alt+F7)
3. unmount /home
4. create `/oldhome`
5. remount the home partition under a new name, e.g. `/oldhome`
6. rsync the files from the "new name mount" to /home with `-a` option
7. remove the home partition from `/etc/fstab`